# Have multiple links in an ul but only first link is used on click event

Tags: javascript, html

I want the user to be able to choose between two links, however, whichever line they select it always runs the first 'href'.

```
<div class="ddmenu-container">
   <div class="ddmenu 2">
    United States
    <ul style="z-index: 6">
      <li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com"> E-Commerce Portal </a></li> 
      <li><a href="https://www.google.com"> Website </a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery code. I assume that it stops running once it finds the first href but I am curious how I can prevent that and allow it to select the second if clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.ddmenu.2 ul').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, you bound a handler to the `ul`, and then you search for all `a` elements within that `ul`, so yes, you'll get the first `href`.

Comment: You know you didn't close the `li` or the `a` in your first one, right? And your closing of the second anchor has an extra bracket.

Comment: can you change this line `<li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com"></i> E-Commerce Portal`   like this `<li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com"> E-Commerce Portal</a></li>`

Comment: Sorry about that, did some poor editing, also have no idea why the Website part is in list form here instead of the actual code. basically its the same as the <li> above it but with a different link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem:**

Well it's obvious that your code always uses the first link `href` because of your following code:

```
$('.ddmenu.2 ul').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

You are attching click to the `ul` and then you are writing `$(this).find('a')` so when it finds a matching link(which is the first), it will proceed with it.

**Solution:**

You need to change your code to attach the click event to `li` elements or directly to `<a>` elements, so change your code to:

```
$('.ddmenu.2 ul li').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```

This way when you call `$(this).find('a')`, it will only fetch inside the clicked `li` element, so it will get the right link.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it worked. I wish i clould upvote but I don't have enough rep. Also sorry for the poor editing, still trying to learn how to post properly on this site.

Comment: I will upvote it for you, Radu, as it's a nice explanation and a good fix

Answer (score 1):

Please correct the HTML part. There are some unclosed tags and typos.

And then change the javascript part as follows:

```
$('.ddmenu.2 ul li').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
});
```